# Years in College Job Requirements for Internships

Tags: internship, applications

So I have noticed many internships requiring people to be a sophomore/junior/senior in college to be qualified for a job. If a summer internship does require you to be in your junior or senior year, but your applying as a sophomore, but will technically be a junior when you'd be in the job over the summer, would you meet the requirement to be allowed to apply?

Comment: If in doubt, contact the company and ask.

Answer (score 2):

In the united states once you get to college the idea of Freshman through Senior are no longer linked to a calendar, except the academic one.

- If you have 0 to 30 college credits you are a Freshman.
- 31 to 60 you are a Sophomore
- 61 to 90 you are a Junior.
- 91 plus you are a Senior.

Because you frequently apply during  a semester most employers of interns know how to add the expected credits for this current semester to the ones you have already completed. In most colleges the student can request a version of the transcript that will include the classes you are currently attending.

In some cases employer will specify exactly the number of years/semesters they want you to have completed.  This is done to make incoming Freshman who have earned a few AP credits from qualifying for the position. It can also be used to eliminate seniors who are on class short and are trying to work as an intern in the summer while taking the last class, and then graduating in the middle of the summer.

If we look at your situation: if you will have 61 or more credits at the end of the spring semester then you will be a Junior during the summer. If you will have 60 credits it is up to the employer.